# I accidentally deposited all my tokens and ETH with with Etherscan, how can I get back?

Tags: tokens

I screwed up the first time on site and I transferred 1 ETH to buy coins then rather than depositing coins into myetherwallet, I used the wrong address and sent to Etherscan. I've been able to see them move around a but dont know how to get back or even if I can. I have 990 coins and $400 worth of ETH just gone. I'm bummed. Can anyone help?

I need step by step instructions how to get my tokens back or my ETH so I can buy more.

Comment: TxHash:0x7a1c02594981308f24d57ded543be1da89db5a491a9a3ec08906d464a6f6176f TxReceipt Status:SuccessBlock Height:5355207 (2080 block confirmations)TimeStamp:8 hrs 10 mins ago (Mar-31-2018 01:55:09 PM +UTC)From:0x64d1e8dba5a37a131515ce6514a57c38d3311c98To:0xf3655c1ef996d401dc05bde9bfeb5cb1331e8570 Value: 0.9998992 Ether ($394.32) Gas Limit: 21000 Gas Used By Txn: 21000 Gas Price: 0.000000005 Ether (5 Gwei) Actual Tx Cost/Fee: 0.000105 Ether ($0.04) Nonce: 0 Input Data: 
0x

Private Note: <To access the private Note feature, you must be logged in>

Answer (score 0):

If you've sent your ETH or tokens to an address which does not belong to you, then there's no way of getting them back.

Comment: So who keeps my money

Comment: Based on the txId you posted above, your money went to whoever owns the account with the address 0xF3655C1eF996D401dC05bDe9bfEB5cB1331E8570. 

If you know who this wallet belongs to, you could try contact them and ask for your ETH back. But if you don't know who it belongs to there isn't really any way of finding out, and your ETH is gone forever unfortunately.

Comment: Could send them a near-empty tx with text as hex in the data field

Comment: That's true, although you'd have to hope that they'd notice the tx, check the data, and convert it to ascii. But it'd cost next to nothing to do so it's probably worth a try.